# Describe the sequence $2,2,1,0,0,1,2,2,...$ using the floor function

Tags: sequences-and-series, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Is there a way to describe the sequence $2,2,1,0,0,1,2,2,1,0,0,1,2,2...$ by using the floor function?

I can describe the series using a sinusoidal function but wanted to get it in terms of a floor function for a tricky proof. The sinusoidal function is:

$u(n)=-\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}sin(\frac{\pi}{3}n-\pi)+1$

Comment: Any thoughts about the answer I posted yesterday, Joseph?

Comment: Earth to Joseph, come in, please.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks so much for the response and creative solution! Originally, I needed this series in an induction proof, but I could get around it by doing the proof by induction for every n=k+6 member and testing n=1,2,3,4,5,6. Either function would work but I stuck with the cosine because it ended up working out nicely with the math. Thank you a bunch though!

Comment: What cosine? I don't see any.

Comment: sorry I meant the sin function

Comment: Welcome back, Joseph.

Answer (score 1):

$\lfloor(n+5)/6\rfloor-\lfloor(n+4)/6\rfloor$ gives the sequence $1,0,0,0,0,0$ repeating. So what you want is $$2\lfloor{n+5\over6}\rfloor-2\lfloor{n+4\over6}\rfloor+2\lfloor{n+4\over6}\rfloor-2\lfloor{n+3\over6}\rfloor+\lfloor{n+3\over6}\rfloor-\lfloor{n+2\over6}\rfloor+\lfloor{n\over6}\rfloor-\lfloor{n-1\over6}\rfloor$$ which simplifies a little to $$2\lfloor{n+5\over6}\rfloor-\lfloor{n+3\over6}\rfloor-\lfloor{n+2\over6}\rfloor+\lfloor{n\over6}\rfloor-\lfloor{n-1\over6}\rfloor$$